# Livebinding a DataSet field to a Form Caption

Tags: delphi, livebindings

I would have thought this obvious, but I don't see a way of doing it, is there a way of binding a dataset field to the caption of a form.  I'm using Delphi XE5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the LiveBindings Designer or the Wizard because the form itself is not listed there.

A possible workaround is to place a TLabel and bind to its Caption.
Then go to the TLinkPropertyToField binding that was created and change the Component property to your form - it will show an Error but you can ignore that and it will work.
After that you can remove the label again.

Comment: I actually discovered this myself soon after, the error is a bit of a worry but it seems to work just fine.